# JasperView fechando todo o sistema

Tags: java, javafx, jasper-reports

Nem sei direito como explicar isso mas vou tentar.

Tenho um sistema feito em JavaFx que exibe relatórios com o Jasper de acordo com o item selecionado, até ai tudo tranquilo, ao selecionar um item e mandar imprimir funciona, porém ao fechar o relatório gerado pelo JasperViewer, todo o sistema fecha junto e o mais estranho, sem nenhuma mensagem de erro.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Se possível compartilhe o código fonte conosco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema que está acontecendo é que o método `show()`, da classe `JasperReportBuilder`, por default ele vai true no `EXIT_ON_CLOSED`, simplesmente tem que passar false ao método, a classe `JasperReportBuilder` tem dois métodos show: `show()` e `show(boolean exitOnClose)`.

```
 JasperReportBuilder.class.newInstance.show(false);
```